# Compiling error | cannot compile cpp program due to compiler parser

Tags: c++, c++11

**Short Description** 
I am trying to compile a short lambda to convert a giving input to string format. My overall class uses a template, i.e template <typename T>. I want to overload << to print-out an object which can be of any type; i.e, int, string, etc. 
For example, let's say that my object is {int age: 12, int* left: null, int* right: null}, I should be able to print something like "{value: "12", left: undefined, right: undefined}". In addition, if object = {string comment: "Distance learning....", int* left: undefined, int* right: undefined}, I should print out, "{value: "Distance learning....", left: undefined, right: undefined}". Below is a copy of the lambda function mark-up to convert from any data-type to a string.

```
std::function<std::string(T)> toString; //declares the blueprint for the lambda function, notice that I am returning a string, and expecting an object of type T, which can be of any type since i'm using a template. 
    toString = [](T value) -> std::string { //Begins the the body of the function
      if (typeid(std::string).name() == typeid(T).name())
      { // not the best way to do this, but here I am checking that the input is already a string, in which case I do not need to convert or anything. 
        return value; //if the input 'value' is already a string, simply return it. 
      }
      //do some stuff to convert the date into a string

      return; // return the final 'value' in string format. 
    };
```

*~Sorry in advance if my comments were confusing.*

**Problem** 
The idea works on paper, however, the problem happens when I have a data-type that is not of type string. Let's say that T == int, walking through the code, the if statement will be skipped, assuming that my condition is set-up correctly, and I should move down. This means that I will not return an int when the function blueprint says that I will return a string.

However, when the compiler goes through my code, it reads it and thinks that I am trying to send-back an int when the function is supposed to send back a string and it throws an error. *"no viable conversion from returned value of type 'int' to function return type 'std::string'"*

for example,

```
//Let T = int, value = 12, so the below parameter equals, int value, which holds the value of 12. 

    toString = [](T value) -> std::string {
      if (typeid(std::string).name() == typeid(T).name())
      { //should failed since typeid(int).name != typeid(std::string).name
        return value;
      }
      //do some stuff to convert the date into a string

      return; // return the final 'value' in string format. 
    };
//However, when the compiler parses the code, it thinks that I am trying to return value, which is of type int. But the function is supposed to return a string.

//In reality, this should not happen since my if statement will take care of it.
```

Does anyone know a work around for this or any idea on how to fix my logic?

Comment: this is exactly the situation for which `if constexpr` is designed for, but you need to use C++17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need at least C++17 to use `if constexpr`.

With `if constexpr` you can write something as

```
 if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<T, std::string> )
     return value
 else
  {
     // something else that return a std::string
  }
```

Only this way you can exclude from the compilation `return value`, when `T` isn't `std::string`, and the body for the `else` case, otherwise.

Observe that I've used the `std::is_same` type-trait to check if `T` and `std::string` are the same type. `std::is_same` is something that the compiler decide compile time. Your `typeid(...).value()` is a run-time value. Suggestion: prefer compile-time type-traits, when possible.

But I need to see a more complete example to show how to use `if constexpr` in your class/struct.

Before C++17, you need two different functions to initialize `tostring`.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I can only use cpp11 for this project.

Comment: @Drio - So you have to develop different function. You should show something more, about your class.